# I want to convert a Fluter list to a Dart list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this list:

```
([1, 2], [C, V])
```

and I want to convert it to this:

```
(([1, 2]), ([C, V]))
```

How can I convert this list from Flutter to Dart?

Comment: There's no difference between a flutter list or dart list. Flutter uses dart

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class:

```
class Tuple {
  final List<dynamic> value;

  Tuple(this.value);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '(${value.toString()})';
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
void main() {
  List<List<dynamic>> originalList = [
    [1, 2],
    ['C', 'V']
  ];

  var formattedList = originalList.map((innerList) => Tuple(innerList)).toList();

  print(formattedList);
}
```

Or use this for not using external class

```
var formattedList = originalList.map((innerList) => '(${innerList.toString()})').toList();
```

Comment: Thanks you! but how can we do if we do not use the Class Tuple?

Comment: ! Hi brother! Suppose that I follow your first method, but how can i modify the dart class original list(originalList)? I want to update the original list to (([1, 2]), ([C, V]))